ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f-%z'
I am trying to create a datetime object from a string formatted like d below:
d = '2024-04-04 12:00:00.123-4'
date = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f-%z')

The error I am receiving:

ValueError: time data '2024-04-04 12:00:00.123-4' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d
%H:%M:%S.%f-%z'

I think the offset is the issue. How would I fix my format code to match the string?

-4 is not a proper match for a timezone offset.

Corrected code :
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = '2024-04-04 12:00:00.123-0400'
date = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

output :
2024-04-04 12:00:00.123000-04:00

here the format for %z  UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (Acc. to documentation)
and you must not use sign with %z sign must be used in strings.
In your code I have corrected -4 to -0400 which is equivalent to -4 hours
and -%z ->  %z ( removing sign in the beginning).
